# Модульная организация проекта в Zend Framework

Tags: framework, php, zend-framework

Имеется проект на Zend Framework 1.12.
Какие параметры необходимо указать в application.ini в случае использования модульной структуры проекта? Как для каждого модуля указать директорию для контроллеров, моделей и представлений?
Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Там вроде всё просто..  У фронтконтроллера (Zend_Controller_Front), можно указать директорию для модулей, а остальные параметры остаются по умолчанию..  Т.е. структура каждого модуля такая:

```
Controllers
Model
Views
```

Подробней писать долго..  Да и в документации вообще-то всё описано

Comment: для каждого модуля свой бутстрап

Answer (score 1):

Например так:

```
resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules"
```